# Is it possible to generate a global list of marked strings at compile time/runtime?

Tags: c++, static, localization, internationalization, c-preprocessor

So, I'm working on translating my C++ app into multiple languages.  What I'm currently using is something like:

```
#define TR(x) (lookupTranslatedString( currentLocale(), x ))
wcout << TR(L"This phrase is in English") << endl;
```

The translations are from a CSV file which maps the english string to the translated string.

```
"This phrase is in English","Nasa Tagalog itong pagsabi"
```

This is simplified, but that's the basic idea.

My question is about generating the list of English phrases that need to be translated.  I just need the CSV with all the english phrases, and blank translated phrases.  I was hoping that it might be possible to either generate this list at compile time or at runtime.  At compiletime I was thinking something like this:

```
#define TR(x) \
    #warning x \
    (lookupTranslatedString( currentLocale(), x ))
```

and then maybe parse the compile log, or something.  This seems not to work so well.

At runtime would also be great.  I was thinking of just starting the app and having a hidden command that would dump the english CSV.  I've seen similar methods used to register commands with a central list, using global variables.  It might look something like this:

```
class TrString
{
public:
    static std::set< std::wstring > sEnglishPhrases;
    TrString( std::wstring english_phrase ) { sEnglishPhrases.insert( english_phrase ); }
};

#define TR(x) do {static TrString trstr(x);} while( false ); (lookupTranslatedString( currentLocale(), x ));
```

I know there's two problems with the above code. I doubt it compiles, but more importantly, in order to generate a list of all english phrases, I'd need to hit every single code path before accessing sEnglishPhrases.

It looks like I'll end up writing a small parser to read through all my code and look for TR strings, which isn't really that tough.  I was just hoping to learn a little more about C++, and if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're almost there.  Taking the last idea:

```
class TrString
{
public:
    static std::set< std::string > sEnglishPhrases;
    std::string phrase;
    TrString(const std::string& english_phrase ):phrase(english_phrase)
    { sEnglishPhrases.insert( english_phrase ); }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, const TrString& o);
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, const TrString& o)
{
    stream << lookupTranslatedString( currentLocale(), o.phrase);
    return stream;
}

#define TR(x) ( TrString(x) )
// ...
std::cout << TR("This phrase is in English") << std::endl;
```

And as you say, you do need to run the code over every `TR()` statement, but you could configure a unit test framework to do this.

My alternative would be to use the above TrString class to make static variables for each module:

```
// unnamed namespace gives static instances
namespace
{
   TrString InEnglish("This phrase is in English");
   // ...
}
```

Now you just need to link in an alternative `main()` to print out TrString:: sEnglishPhrases

Comment: It looks like this is about the best solution, which is to say that there's no really clean solution.  I guess that makes sense, since everyone I've seen, from gettext to Qt all just implement a little parser.

Answer (score 2):

You could just build a quick script to parse the file and strip what you need.

```
awk '/TR\(L"[^"]*")/ {print}' plop.c
```

If you need somthing slightly more complex then perl is your friend.

Comment: Yes, this is what it looks like I'll end up doing.  I was just wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for seems very similar to what [GNU gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html) does. In particular, look at the [xgettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Template) tool.